# How to extract specific value from JWT React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, axios, jwt

I don't know how to extract only a specific value from my JWT token, I use react-jwt as my React library to decode my token, when I console.log I get this:

`Object { userId: "850dff98-54fb-4059-9e95-e44f5c30be0f", iat: 1698866016 }`

And I'd like to extract only the value of userId to put it in a localstorage like this: localStorage.setItem("userId", "the value")

```
import {useJwt} from "react-jwt"

export async function JWTDecode() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")

    const { decodedToken } = useJwt(token!);
    console.log(decodedToken)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you could type it as they suggested in the [Github Issue](https://github.com/gustavo0197/react-jwt/issues/22)

```
interface TokenPayload {
  userId: string;
  iat: number;
}

const { decodedToken, isExpired } = useJwt<TokenPayload>(token);
```

Had to reference the attributes using `?` but that should be fine,
[Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/green-tdd-hzyjg3?file=/src/Test.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the string with JSON.parse first, then you can access the members.

```
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
const tokenObj = JSON.parse(token);
const userId = tokenObj.userId;
```

You should probably also add some error handling and validation in there to make sure the token object is valid.